# Store complex eigenvectors from linalg.eig into an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm having problems storing the out put of `numpy.linalg.eig()`. I want to store then into two different array. This is the way I've tried:

```
vec1 = np.zeros(y.shape[0],dtype=complex)
vec2 = np.zeros(y.shape[0],dtype=complex)
for i in np.arange(y.shape[0]):
    val,vec= np.linalg.eig(rho_t[:,:,i])
    vec1[i] = vec[0]
    vec2[i] = vec[1]
```

The ERROR message is the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-389-791a7e5e4801> in <module>
      3 for i in np.arange(y.shape[0]):
      4     val,vec= np.linalg.eig(rho_t[:,:,i])
----> 5     vec1[i] = vec[0]
      6     vec2[i] = vec[1]
      7     #vec2[i] = np.array(sol[1][1])

TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

No idea what is the problem, can somebody help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html

> The normalized (unit “length”) eigenvectors, such that the column
>   v[:,i] is the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue w[i].

so perhaps the solution is this:

```
for i in np.arange(y.shape[0]):
    val,vec= np.linalg.eig(rho_t[:,:,i])
    vec1[i] = vec[:,0]
    vec2[i] = vec[:,1]
```